# html5 / js websocket: setting event handlers *after* connecting?

Tags: javascript, html, events, websocket, event-handling

A lot of HTML5 websocket example code does something like this:

```js
websocket = new WebSocket('ws://example.com');
websocket.onopen = MyOpenHandler;
websocket.onerror = MyErrorHandler;
```

Of course with the intention of `MyOpenHandler` being called upon connecting, or `MyErrorHandler` if the connection fails.

**Exactly when does the actual connection takes place** and is the above event handling approach **guaranteed** to work, even if the connection happens or fails *immediately*?

What I mean is, wouldn't an approach like this make more sense:

```
websocket = new WebSocket;
websocket.onopen = MyOpenEventHandler;
websocket.onerror = MyErrorHandler;
websocket.connect('ws://example.com');
```

I.e. connect *after* the event handlers have been set, to be 100% sure they are being called when appropriate.

Or am I just being paranoia here, and is the reference implementation (the topmost example) actually correct?

**Addendum**

I did some additional testing with the following code:

```
var websocket = new WebSocket("ws://localhost:8000"); // this connection will fail
alert("Created the websocket, now let's set the event handler");
websocket.onerror = function(e) { alert("Could not connect") }
```

This fails, the "Could not connect" alert does NOT appear. However if I remove that former alert (the one on line 2), it does.

This kinda worries me. Apparently it's possible the connection already failed before I got the chance to set the onerror event handler, thus the handler never gets called. How can I be 100% certain that the connection is guaranteed to take place *after* I set the appropriate handlers?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSocket see the example

Comment: this would requiring studying the actual WebSocket object to see how it behaves and what methods get called first

Comment: @AthMav yes that's what I'm using, but I'm a bit concerned with the fact that event handlers are being assigned *after* the event may already have taken place.

Comment: @sietse85 I guess that's an option, but I was kinda hoping somebody else has done something like that already and can share some wisdom here.

Answer (score 0):

https://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-websockets-20110419/#the-websocket-interface

I believe that number 6 below answers your question.

When the WebSocket() constructor is invoked, the UA must run these steps:

1. Parse a WebSocket URL's components from the url argument, to obtain host, port, resource name, and secure. If this fails, throw a SYNTAX_ERR exception and abort these steps.
2. If port is a port to which the user agent is configured to block access, then throw a SECURITY_ERR exception. (User agents typically block access to well-known ports like SMTP.)
   Access to ports 80 and 443 should not be blocked, including the unlikely cases when secure is false but port is 443 or secure is true but port is 80.
3. If protocols is absent, let protocols be an empty array.
   Otherwise, if protocols is present and a string, let protocols instead be an array consisting of just that string.
4. If any of the values in protocols occur more than once or contain characters with Unicode code points less than U+0021 or greater than U+007E (i.e. the space character or any characters that are not printable ASCII characters), then throw a SYNTAX_ERR exception and abort these steps.
5. Let origin be the ASCII serialization of the origin of the script that invoked the WebSocket() constructor, converted to ASCII lowercase.
6. Return a new WebSocket object, and continue these steps in the background (without blocking scripts).
7. Establish a WebSocket connection to a host host, on port port (if one was specified), from origin, with the flag secure, with resource name as the resource name, with protocols as the (possibly empty) list of protocols, and with the defer cookies flag set.

**UPDATE**

https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/web-sockets.html#feedback-from-the-protocol

When the WebSocket connection is established, the user agent must queue a task to run these steps:

1. Change the readyState attribute's value to OPEN (1).
2. Change the extensions attribute's value to the extensions in use, if is not the null value. [WSP]
3. Change the protocol attribute's value to the subprotocol in use, if is not the null value. [WSP]
4. Fire an event named open at the WebSocket object.

NOTE

Since the algorithm above is queued as a task, there is no race condition between the WebSocket connection being established and the script setting up an event listener for the open event.

Comment: Thanks. See my addendum, I added some test code. I wonder if this is a violation of the protocol? (this was tested in Firefox, latest version)

Comment: Because of the alert, the onerror hadn't a chance to get "registered". That's why it didnt fire. If it was a console.log it would propably fire.

Comment: Yes, but what worries me about this, is that apparently it starts connecting immediately. It can imagine it's very well possible that it fails *immediately* (e.g. if no internet connection available, or the websocket url or domain is wrong). I find it strange there seems to be no way to explicitly set any event handlers **before** doing something (in this case, attempt to connect) that can cause those events.

Comment: Please read my answer. It's there. Step 6... But if you do something to stop the execution like an alert then of course it will fail